# Check if SCNNodes overlap in view

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

How to detect if two `SCNNodes` are overlapping in `SCNView`? They are added in `different x an z axis` position but from point of camera they look like they overlap together. I want to detect this and then move one of them up or down.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who will struggle with this problem later...
I fixed this with [simdWorldPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881856-simdworldposition?language=objc) property of SCNNode. Here is the code:

```
let overlapping = wayNamedLocationNode.infoTextNodes.filter { overlappingTextNode in
                    let x = abs(overlappingTextNode.simdWorldPosition.x - textNode.simdWorldPosition.x)
                    let z = abs(overlappingTextNode.simdWorldPosition.z - textNode.simdWorldPosition.z)
                    if ((x < 4 && x > 0) || (z < 4 && z > 0)) {
                        return true
                    } else {
                        return false
                    }
                }
if overlapping.count > 0 {
     overlapping.forEach { $0.removeFromParentNode() }
}
```

Firstly I found all overlapping nodes and then I simply remove them from parent node.